# FME: No attributes exported when writing to SHAPE file

Tags: fme-form, fields-attributes

**Setup**:
I have some input data (SHAPE) which I use a *Clipper* transformer on. Depending on the result of the Clipper, I assign a value to an attribute. In the end I assign the two results/streams to a SHAPE *writer*.

**Problem**:
When I run the project my resulting SHAPE file has no attributes.

**Observations**:

- If I open my output (by clicking on the arrow/triangle next to the OUTPUT) on the transformers before my writer, the attributes are available and the same for both the streams.
- If I select *Fanout By Attribute* in *Properties* in my writer, all my attributes are available. If I select the *User Attributes* tab, no attributes are listed.

Through these observations, my attributes seems valid *(supported by the transformers and the Fanout)* and unique thus I see no reason why the writer shouldn't export them.

**Solution**:
Like **GIS-Jonathan** suggest, I have added my writer and selected the *static schema*. Then I right click my writer and select *Copy Attributes From ...* and select the desired source. Now I have all the attributes I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like one of those annoying schema problems. When you placed the writer, did you place it as a "static schema" or a "dynamic schema"?

There are several possible problems but I suspect its the first one:

**Static Schema**

Do you have the attributes listed under your writer like this? 
[image]

If not you'll need to add them on the *User Attributes* tab (The + button) that you reference in your question. They should also have a little green arrow next to each attribute like I have here (the light grey line isn't necessary if they have the same name).

**Dynamic Schema**

This is where you have multiple different schemas (different sets of attributes) all going to the same writer. Some explanation of them here:
http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Dynamic-Schema-Examples-FME2011 and: http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist54/

Comment: I used the *static schema* and I don't have the attributes listed under my writer. I normally add the attributes myself, but since (from my point of view) it is straight forward which attributes the writer should make available to me, I want it to do so - and not let me do something that is already done automatically by the translators. An inspector knows how to fetch the attributes.

Comment: In that case you'll need to set it to a _Dynamic Schema_. With a static Schema you **have** to specify the output attributes or you simply won't get any; this can be done easily by right-clicking on the writer and selecting either `Copy Attributes From Feature Type` (i.e. a reader) or `Copy Attributes From Transformer`.

Comment: Oh yes, I can't guarantee that a Dynamic Schema will pick up any attributes that are created during the translation - they just clone the input schema. So in that case I think you'll have to manually add the created attributes to the _User Attributes_ tab.

Comment: I get what you are proposing, but I don't understand why its necessary :) I guess it has something to do with database stuff. I have used your *Copy Attributes From Transformer* approach and it seem to work just like a charm! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why it's necessary I leave for @MarkIreland to explain (he works for Safe). I'd guess its to give you more control, especially over the data type (is it a varchar 20 or int? etc - FME is poor at figuring that stuff out itself as you'll see from the "copy from transformer").